# Search for questions with at most n views

Tags: support, questions, search, views

We can search for `views:N` and get questions with at least N views.  How would I search for questions with *at most* N views?

I'd like to know how usual or unusual it is that nobody clicks on my question.  The only comparison I have is to see how many [Tumbleweed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed) badges others have collected.  Except that it isn't awarded multiple times…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the range operator. From the [search help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

> Range Operators
>
> To search for only questions that fall within a particular range for score, number of answers, or number of views, you can enter an upper or lower parameter, or a range.
>
> - `score:-1` or `score:-1..` will both return posts with a score greater than or equal to -1
> - `views:500..1000` or `views:500-1000` will return posts with 500 to 1000 views
> - `answers:..3` will return questions with 3 or fewer answers

So you could search using something like `views:1-N` or `views:..N` (`views:-N` doesn't seem to work).

Example:

[image]

Notice that the search options shows "views<= 3" on the right of the example.

Note that this search may return posts with views greater than N because

> We do not reindex a post every time someone views it as that'd be pretty wasteful. As a consequence, older posts that had no activity in a while (voting, editing, etc.) will potentially have a rather out-of-sync value for views as far as search is concerned.
>
> <sub>**Source: answer to [Getting questions with >N views despite searching for questions with ≤N views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283285/299342)**</sub>

Comment: When I try that on [Stats Stack Exchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=vIews%3A..5), I get 6747 results.  Clicking of the first question, it tells me it has 116 views.  Why does it give me questions with more than 5 (in my attempt) views?  Edited question.

Comment: @gerrit It seems to include some posts that are a bit above the threshold, but why that's the case is probably only something the SE devs can answer (possibly with a bug report). It definitely filters out a lot of posts, though.

Comment: @gerrit I almost suspect Viewed is something different from Viewcount, compare your results with my [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/523489)