# Getting questions with >N views despite searching for questions with ≤N views

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, search, views

Trying to [search for questions with at most n views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283281/search-for-questions-with-at-most-n-views), I'm getting questions with more views than asked for.  For example, I tried to search for `views:1..5` on CrossValidated, but I'm getting results with more views:

[image: Views 1…5]

But the [highest linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137017/how-do-i-combine-stochastic-policy-with-q-value-iteration) actually has 117 views at the time of writing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We do not reindex a post every time someone views it as that'd be pretty wasteful. As a consequence, older posts that had no activity in a while (voting, editing, etc.) will potentially have a rather out-of-sync value for views as far as search is concerned.

At the moment this is by design since searching by views is fairly rare in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Ok; so there is no way of really searching low-view questions, then.  Pity, but I can understand that it is not a priority.

Comment: @gerrit if you want no cache, use sede instead.

Answer (score 4):

[Adam explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283285/245360) what the problem is with the view count statistics. [Braiam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/213575/braiam) suggested to use SEDE, which I though was useful to do. Remember that SEDE is updated once a week, so the views count might deviate from the current view count as well as the post score.

You can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/620588/questions-filtered-by-number-of-views?MinViews=0&MaxViews=10) to get the top 100 questions matching the view count filter:

```sql
select top 100 Id [Post Link]
,      viewcount
from   posts
where  1=1
and    PostTypeId = 1
and    (##MinViews## is null or viewcount >= ##MinViews##)
and    (##MaxViews## is null or viewcount <= ##MaxViews##)
```